# React modal is not showing in the center of the screen

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

With the help of the community, I have been able to final have my modal pop-up working on my reat website.

The modal code is as below:

```js
import React from "react";
import '../../assets/styles/GenericTheme.css'
import { Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

class LoginRegisterModal extends React.Component {  
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {show: false};
    }
      
    open = () => {
        this.setState({show: true});
    }
    
    close = () => {
        this.setState({show: false});
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const { show } = this.props;
        if (prevProps.show !== show) {
          if (show) {
            this.open(); // open if parent says to
          } else {
            this.close(); // close if parent says to
          }
        }
      }
      
    render() {  
        const styleModal = {
            width:770,
            height:480,
            backgroundColor:"#ffffffff",
            borderRadius:21.5,
            boxShadow: "0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14)",
        }
        return (         
        <Modal show={this.state.show} style={styleModal} >
            <Modal.Body>test</Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.close}>
              Close
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
        );  
    }  
}  
  
export default LoginRegisterModal;
```

The modal is called by the react-bootstrap Navs components:

```
const menuLoginRegister = <Nav.Link ref="LoginRegisterModal" eventKey={1} href="#" onClick={this.openLogin}>{TextContents.MenuLoginRegister}</Nav.Link>;
```

And I have added the modal in the return function like below:

```
return (
            <div>
            <Navbar className="village-header" width="100" expand="lg">
                ....
            </Navbar>
            <LoginRegisterModal show={this.state.showLogin} 
              onHide={() => this.setState({ showLogin: false })}/>
            </div>
            );
```

The only issues is that the modal keep being displayed on the top left corner and not centered in the screen. 
I tried to use a center in the style but it still not move it to the center.

Any idea how to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: can you please provide sandbox link for this so , can easily debugg css .

Comment: Hi @VyasArpit not sure to understand. I have added the snipper option

Comment: Applying a style prop to the modal isn't doing what you think it's doing. To apply styles to the dialog, use the `dialogClassName` prop on `Modal` instead of inline style.

Comment: Also, use max-width with a percentage of the viewport width to control the width in the dialog class.

Comment: thanks @djfdev . I thought it would be the same. what's the difference? because it's the same css  ?

Comment: The difference is which DOM element the CSS gets applied to. The modal is made up of a number of different divs. To get the results you want you need to make sure it applies to the correct one.